# How to compare structs faster (who met the most people problem)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I will start by saying that I'm not a native speaker so please excuse me my grammatical errors.

I'm an university student and my task is the following: I have an input that tells me the number of people, and then every line contains the time of arrival and the time of exit, both natural numbers separated by a space.

I have to find the (index of the) person who met the most people and then output the number of meetings that person had.

Example input and output:

[image]

If person A has datestamps of 3 and 6 and person B has 6 and 7, it is still considered a meeting.

I already solved this problem with a fixed size array of structs that compares every person to everybody else to find out the number of meetings and then searched for the person with the most meetings.

My problem is that this code is very slow and I must hadle inputs consisting of maximum 200000 people and timestamps ranging from 1 to 1000000.

This - compare everyone with everyone else - solution works for small sample sizes, but there is no way it can work for 200000 structs.
Also, this code has to successfully run under 0.2 sec.

What is a faster way to solve this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int maxN = 20000;

struct Data {
    int arrival;
    int departure;
    int meetings = -1;
};

int main()
{
    Data x[maxN];
    int N;

    ///input
    cin >> N;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> x[i].arrival;
        cin >> x[i].departure;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if ( ((x[i].arrival >= x[j].arrival && x[i].arrival <= x[j].departure) || (x[i].departure >= x[j].arrival && x[i].departure <= x[j].departure)) ||  ((x[j].arrival >= x[i].arrival && x[j].arrival <= x[i].departure) || (x[j].departure >= x[i].arrival && x[j].departure <= x[i].departure)) ) {
                x[i].meetings++;

            }
        }
    }

    int maxInd = 0;
    int maximum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (x[i].meetings > maximum){
            maxInd = i;
            maximum = x[i].meetings;
        }
    }

    ///output
    cout << maxInd+1 << endl;
    cout << maximum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is really not a C++ issue -- it is an algorithms/data structure issue.  Once you do this: `for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) { for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){`, you've lost the game in terms of speed, no matter how much you want to tweak the structs.

Comment: If the objects you are comparing are both PODs, you probably cannot do better than `memcmp()`. But, probably `operator==` does that for you under the hood and is the more sensible choice..

Comment: Is there a minimum and maximum `erkezes` and `tavozas`? If so, that opens up some options for algorithms.

Comment: Sorry, I realized this is indeed a generic question, not a specifically c++ one. erkezes and tavozas are both between 1 and 1000000.

Comment: It would be good if you changed the variable names to english. Having varible names that have no meaning to me makes reading the code difficult to a point that honestly I didnt even bother to try to understand it in every detail

Comment: I would like to repost this question in an algorithm/data structure topic but as I'm not a native speaker, I don't know how to phrase my question correctly. Could you give me some tips?

Comment: you dont have to repost anything, simply change the c++ tag with the algorithm one. Or perhaps leave the c++ tag as you already have an implementation in c++

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 you are right, I will change them to English. Sorry!

Comment: added the tag for you

Comment: Break each person into an open (+1) and a close (-1) event. Let's say we had an array `arr` of events, where if a person had datestamps `[L, R]` then we have `arr[L] += 1` and `arr[R + 1] -= 1`. The culmulative sum of the array will result in an array where `arr[i]` is the number of people with a meeting a time `i`. The number of people who  intersect `[L, R]` is simply the number of people who already had a meeting at `L` (`arr[L]`) plus the number of number of open events on `[L, R]`. With preprocessing both of these can be computed in `O(1)`.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thanks for the tag, I cleaned up the code! I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @Primusa This sounds interesting, I need a little time while I try to understand it. I'm still a beginner so this process will be a little slower for me

Comment: @Primuse please post answers as answers

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 i don't really know enough cpp to make an adequate answer, but if i throw the idea out there maybe someone who does will :)

Comment: @Primusa the quesiton is about the algorithm, look at my answer, the little code I added is just to illustrate what I am saying, I guess pseudo code would be fine as well

Comment: @Primusa The key to all of this is to sort the data in some strategic way, and then linearly process the sorted data.  Sorting is logarithmic using `std::sort`, thus cutting the time down drastically.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie do you have any idea how should I sort the data?

Comment: @Primusa what do you mean by "both of these can be computed in O(1)" ?

Comment: @Primusa -- Forget about writing a program for now.  Take out a pencil and paper, look at the data you have in the question.  Can you arrange it in a way where the problem becomes easier?  What if you could put the "1 10" first in the list, then "2 3", etc.?  Then process this list in some way, now that the start times are sorted.  If that doesn't work, then sort by a different criteria, again, all on paper first.  That's how these problems are solved -- not by writing a program and looking at loops, but by visualizing how to solve the problem on paper using pictures, lines, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you do realize that I'm not the one asking the question right?

Comment: @erdostamasa both of these can be computed in `O(1)` means that they are both constant time operations. In the soution I described above the number of people who had a meeting starting at `L` is just `arr[L]` (getting an element in an array happens in constant time), and the number of open events in `[L, R]` can be found by preprocessing with prefix sums and then querying each sum in `O(1)`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the comments were meant for @erdostamasa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by creating a vector and storing the 100.000 points of time in it.
I added 1 to each index where a person came in, stayed, and left.

Working with 100.000 long vectors, I managed to solve this problem with only one for loop se it ran reasonably fast.

Answer (score 1):

I will only give you a starting point...

If I had to solve it, i would start by defining the following structure:

```
 struct come_or_go {
      size_t person_index;
      int time;
      bool arrival; // true for arrival, false for leaving
 };
```

Next I would read the input into a `vector<come_or_go>` with two entries for each person. One when it arrives and one when it leaves. Next I'd sort that vector with respect to the elements `time` member. Finally I'd try to come up with a clever idea that requires to traverse this vector only once.

So far thats all I can provide, maybe I will update when I can give more hints. Hope this helps to push you into a differernt direction, because your brute force simply looses by complexity. Instead of trying to get details of it "faster" you need to change your overall approach.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will think about this! Yes, my solution is good for small samples but completely useless for bigger data sizes. I need a radically different approach indeed.